# Tooltip materialize doesnt appear in the top of each element

Tags: html, css, tooltip, materialize

Hi I´m having some problems with my tooltip, i want that it appear in the top of a diferente element. like this:

[Photo of how i need the tooltip work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtj2q.jpg)

Right now i´m using an SVG and i want to do it like a dynamic map.

```
 <a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip" data-html="true"   href="">
           <path class="st3" d="M1052.7,428c-4.3,1-7.1,4.8-7.1,9.2c0,1,0.1,1.9,0.4,2.7c0.3,0.9,0.7,1.8,1.2,2.6c0.1,0.2,4.8,6.7,6.9,9.5
               c0.5,0.7,1.4,0.7,1.9,0c2.1-2.9,6.8-9.3,7-9.6c0.5-0.8,0.9-1.6,1.2-2.5c0.3-0.9,0.4-1.8,0.4-2.7
               C1064.6,431.1,1059,426.4,1052.7,428z M1055.1,441.4c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2s4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2
               C1059.3,439.5,1057.4,441.4,1055.1,441.4z"/>
               </a>
            </g>
```

But my result of my code is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yqKE.png)

Comment: Please add your html and css code then everyone can guide you better. in stack overflow you can use codesnippet.